# import so file from different folder

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, import, shared-libraries

I am using ubuntu 20.04 and python3. I want to import so file "ext.so" like this:

impot Ext

from another code. But the so file is in different folder. What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the **right way to do it**?

your project should be structured like so:

```
-head
--sub1
---Ext.so
--sub2
---caller.py
```

you should have <s>`head`</s> the folder containing `head` in your pythonpath somehow (by installing the python module using distutils, or just having `head` as your working directory or added by modifying `PYTHONPATH` in `.bashrc`, or appending it to `sys.path` in your script), and you should use

```
from head.sub1 import Ext
```

granted that your `.so` file is a python extension and not some sort of dll, anyone installing your project should be able to run your code without any problems.

however, there is definitely nothing stopping you from adding `sub1` to your pythonpath and just `import Ext`.

**Edit:** i am sorry, if `head` is in pythonpath, you only need to import from sub1, not head, so you should have the folder containing head in your pythonpath, my bad.

Comment: adding path to pythonpath required __init__.py right?